# sub app lazy loading within an angular micro front end in single-spa

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, single-spa, single-spa-angular

I'm using single-spa library to create micro-front-ends. I'm trying to implement lazy loading in one of microfrontend. Normal routing is working fine but when I try to lazy load a module in one microfrontend it doesn't load and gives error.

[https://github.com/single-spa/single-spa-angular/issues/116](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CxnG.png)

I'm facing exactly same issue and use the method he tried to resolve issue but I still got exceptions[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CxnG.png)

Comment: I guess I have found the answer. You have to add deployUrl in you angular.json file and that's it

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have found the answer. You have to add deployUrl in you angular.json file and that's it

Comment: Please don not answer your own questions, instead edit the original answer and provide the solution there. Then it's at the top of the page for others to see as well.

Comment: Sure I'ill keep that in mind